# logic for adjusting max number in array to min number in second array

Tags: arrays, matlab, logic, numeric, numerical-methods

Greetings all

logic for adjusting max number in array to min number in second array

I have an array "A"

```
A=[0 .1 .2 .3 .4 .5 .6 .7 .8 .9 1 .9 .8 .7 .6 .5 .4 .3 .2 .1 0 -.1 -.2 -.3 -.4 -.5 -.6 -.7 -.8 -.9 -1 -.9 -.8 -.7 -.6 -.5 -.4 -.3 -.2 -.1]
```

And I want the second array to be going in the "opposite" direction so when the numbers are going high in array "A" the numbers in array "B" should be going low

example of what array "B" should look like (and A again for reference)

```
B=[1 .9 .8 .7 .6 .5 .4 .3 .2 .1 0 -.1 -.2 -.3 -.4 -.5 -.6 -.7 -.8 -.9 -1 -.9 -.8 -.7 -.6 -.5 -.4 -.3 -.2 -.1 0 .1 .2 .3 .4 .5 .6 .7 .8 .9]
A=[0 .1 .2 .3 .4 .5 .6 .7 .8 .9 1 .9 .8 .7 .6 .5 .4 .3 .2 .1 0 -.1 -.2 -.3 -.4 -.5 -.6 -.7 -.8 -.9 -1 -.9 -.8 -.7 -.6 -.5 -.4 -.3 -.2 -.1]
```

I tried using this logic but it makes everything positive of course

```
arrayB=-abs(arrayA).+abs(max(arrayA));
```

but that didn't work I'm using matlab but if someone knows the correct logic I can convert it over the matlab syntax

tia

The numbers represent different amplitudes of a signal so when the amplitude of one signal arrayA is going up the other signal arrayB should be going down.  There is "overlap"

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for. I thought `max(A) - A` matched your description somewhat, but for the steps from the 11th to the 20th and entry, both `A` and `B` have numbers going down, and for entries 31 to the end, the differences go up in both cases. Are you sure entries 12 through 30 of B should be negative?

Comment: @Christopher Creutzig ok the numbers represent different amplitudes of a signal so when the amplitude of one signal arrayA is going up the other signal arrayB should be going down.

Comment: That still reads like B goes into the wrong direction for the entries listed above. Try `plot(A); hold on; plot(B, 'r');` to see what I mean: from 11 to 21, both signals are decreasing.

Comment: A good website to find a formula for a sequence is The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences [http://oeis.org/](http://oeis.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your title and description are *very* confusing, and I'm unable to tell from them what you are trying to do. However, looking at the desired output array `B` that you want to generate from your input array `A`, I *can* give you a couple of operations that will do that transformation for you:

```
B = max(A)-cumsum([0 abs(diff(A))].*sign(A+eps));
```

This finds the [absolute](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/abs.html) [differences](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/diff.html) in values along array `A`, multiplies these differences by the [sign](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sign.html) of the elements of `A` (counting 0 as positive by adding [EPS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/eps.html) to the signal), takes the [cumulative sum](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cumsum.html) of these values, then subtracts them from the [maximum value](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/max.html) in `A`.

Another solution in this case is simply to create a circular shift of `A` using [array indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f1-85462.html). For example, shifting the array `A` such that its maximum value is at the beginning of the array will give you the desired array `B`:

```
[~,maxIndex] = max(A);
B = A([maxIndex:end 1:maxIndex-1]);
```

Comment: Yes the B = max(A)-cumsum([0 abs(diff(A))].*sign(A+eps));  works perfectly sorry for the weird description but I just didn't know another way to describe it that's why I added the arrays as example

Answer (score 0):

Rick,

Is it as simple as B[i] = 1 - abs(A[i]) ... or am I missing something?

The negatives soon stop lining up, which makes it difficult to see the relationship.

Cheers. Keith.

---

**EDIT:** Nope, it's not that simple!

There is no "ordinary computation" which will produce these results.

It's all good untill we get upto `.1  0 -.1` ... which produces `-.9 -1 -.9`

I guess you'd have to "walk through it" by 10's, swapping the sign of the result after each 10.

```
A=[0 .1 .2 .3 .4 .5 .6 .7 .8 .9 1  .9  .8  .7  .6  .5  .4  .3  .2  .1  0 -.1 -.2 -.3 -.4 -.5 -.6 -.7 -.8 -.9 -1 -.9 -.8 -.7 -.6 -.5 -.4 -.3 -.2 -.1]
B=[1 .9 .8 .7 .6 .5 .4 .3 .2 .1 0 -.1 -.2 -.3 -.4 -.5 -.6 -.7 -.8 -.9 -1 -.9 -.8 -.7 -.6 -.5 -.4 -.3 -.2 -.1  0  .1  .2  .3  .4  .5  .6  .7  .8  .9]
```

Does that make ANY sense? You can see why I didn't do Higher Level maths.

Cheers. Keith.

Answer (score 0):

Does the following code does more or less what you want?

```
Ad = diff(A);
B = cumsum([max(A) -Ad]);
```

Comment: @Egon thanks but the numbers don't match arrayB as you can see there are a bunch of numbers that go over 1 when I execute your code and none of the numbers in my arrayB go over 1, but thanks for trying

Output of your code:
1 0.9 0.8 0.7 0.6 0.5 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.1 1.11022e-16 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8 1.9 2 1.9 1.8 1.7 1.6 1.5 1.4 1.3 1.2 1.1

Comment: @Rickt T: just like @Christopher Creutzig, I think your description is ambiguous or wrong in some way. Look at the values around index 11, in A you have [... .8 .9 1  .9  .8 ....], the same range in B is [... .2 .1 0 -.1 -.2 ...]. So A increases up to 1 and then decreases; B decreases to 0 and *keeps* decreasing in contradiction to what your problem description states (or how I interpret it anyhow).

Comment: Note that your code is just a convoluted way of writing `max(A)-A`, since `A(1)==0`.

Comment: @Christopher Creutzig: you're right for `A(1) == 0`, for `A(1) ~= 0` it does something else. But not the desired output anyhow.

Comment: @Egon: Right, it computes `max(A) - A + A(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

This will also create the correct answer

```
A=[0 .1 .2 .3 .4 .5 .6 .7 .8 .9 1 .9 .8 .7 .6 .5 .4 .3 .2 .1 0 -.1 -.2 -.3 -.4 -.5 -.6 -.7 -.8 -.9 -1 -.9 -.8 -.7 -.6 -.5 -.4 -.3 -.2 -.1]';

B=circshift(A,30)
```